# Constrain multiple Regression for symmetric Stiffness

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, derivative, constrained-regression, constraint

I want to do a 3-degree polynomial regression like

$$y_i=a_0+\sum_{u=1}^{k} a_{u}x_{i,u}+\sum_{1\leq u \leq v \leq k} a_{u,v} x_{i,u}x_{i,v}+\sum_{1\leq u \leq v\leq w \leq k}a_{u,v,w}x_{i,u}x_{i,v}x_{i,w} +\varepsilon_i,$$
thus that in vector form I have
$$
y_i=\hat{\mathbf{x}}_i^T\mathbf{\beta}+\varepsilon_i.
$$
With $i$ being the observation number and $k$ being the dimension of  $\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^k$ . 
I do this three times, as $\mathbf{y}$ has the same dimension as $\mathbf{x}$. This way I can calculate
$$
\mathbf{y}_i=\underline{\mathbf{\beta}}^T\hat{\mathbf{x}}_i=f(\mathbf{x})
%\qquad \underline{\mathbf{\beta}}\in\mathbb{R}^{\frac{1}{6}\left((k+2)^3-k-2\right)\times k}
.
$$
The vector $\hat{\mathbf{x}}(\mathbf{x})$ could for example look like 
$$
\hat{\mathbf{x}}(\mathbf{x})= \begin{bmatrix} x_{1}^3&x_{1}^2x_{2}&...&x_1^2& x_1x_2&...&x_1&x_2&...&1 \end{bmatrix}^T
$$

In my case the dimensions of the matrices are $$\underline{\mathbb{\beta}}\in \mathbb{R}^{20 \times 3},\qquad \mathbf{x}_i\in\mathbb{R}^{20\times 1}.$$

My Problem is that I have the additional constraint that the stiffness or derivative $\mathbf{K}=\frac{\delta \mathbf{y}}{\delta \mathbf{x}}$ must be symmetric as
$$
\frac{\delta \mathbf{y}}{\delta \mathbf{x}}-\left(\frac{\delta \mathbf{y}}{\delta \mathbf{x}}\right)^T=0,\Leftrightarrow
\underline{\mathbf{\beta}}^T\frac{\delta\hat{\mathbf{x}}}{\delta\mathbf{x}}-\frac{\delta\hat{\mathbf{x}}}{\delta\mathbf{x}}^T\underline{\mathbf{\beta}}=0.
$$
From the example above the Jacobian $\frac{\delta\hat{\mathbf{x}}}{\delta\mathbf{x}}$ would look like
$$
\frac{\delta\hat{\mathbf{x}}}{\delta\mathbf{x}}=\begin{bmatrix} 3x_{1}^2&2x_{1}x_{2}&...&2x_1& x_2&...&1&0&...&0 \\
&x_{1}^2&...&0& 1&...&1&0&...&0 \\
\vdots
\end{bmatrix}^T.
$$
Is there a way to include this constraint? I have already found the possibility of linear constraint regression, but I cannot think of a way to formulate my constraint in the form  $\mathbf{C}\mathbf{\beta}=\mathbf{d}$.

I am not from the machine learning field and appreciate any help or comments.

Comment: Could you explain what this "$\delta$" notation means? The usual derivative of the function $x\to x^\prime \beta$ with respect to $x$ is just $\beta$, which--being non-square--cannot possibly be symmetric.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the question, I use polynomial regression and thus the vector $\hat{\mathbf{x}}$ is dependent on ${\mathbf{x}}$ in a polynomial way. With $\delta$ I mean the partial derivative. I have clarified my question in this regard. 
Of course the Jacobian and the parameters $\underline{\mathbf{\beta}}$ are not square, but their product is. I would want this product to become symmetric.

Comment: OK, thank you for the clarification.  But now it appears your constraint is *exactly* in the form $C\beta=0$ that you require, because, given $x$, it obviously is a linear combination of the entries in $\beta$.  There seems to be nothing left to add: write down $C$ and proceed.

Comment: @whuber Thanks, your answer is impressively simple. However, I cannot implement it this way since, the matrix $\tilde{{C}}({\beta})= {{\beta}}^T\frac{\delta\hat{{x}}}{\delta{x}}-\frac{\delta\hat{{x}}}{\delta{x}}^T{{\beta}} \in {R}^{3 \times 3}$. In order to write this in the form ${C}{\beta}={d}$ the matrix elements of $\tilde{{C}}$ may only depend on the matching row of ${\beta}$. E.g. to find the first row of ${C}$, $\tilde{{C}}_{1,2}$ must only depend $\beta_{:,2}$. I could write $\beta$ in one vector but I have to think about this more.